# Prevent tmux from exiting when script finishes

Tags: shell, command-line, tmux

I'd like to prevent tmux from exiting automatically when the script finishes. For example, I have a command something like this(below), this does run a server for an app, but sometimes this unexpectedly exits with an error. When that happens, I'm unable to check what was wrong with the code, command.

```
tmux new-session -d -s "visited" 'bash -ic "visited --server"';
```

Following one is a simplified command of what I'd like to do.

```
tmux new-session -d -s "pwd" 'bash -c pwd' # but actually I need to load .bashrc
tmux a -t pwd # this should attach to the shell, but in my environment this does show "can't find session pwd" since the shell is already exited
```

I read a github [issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2081) and tried to add `set exit-empty off` to ~/.tmux.conf and restart the server `tmux kill-server` and re-tried the above, but seemed it doesn't work.

Comment: `bash -c command` starts a Bash instance, runs `command`, and exits.

Comment: Simply: `tmux new-session -d -s "pwd" 'bash -c "pwd;read"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let tmux create a normal session and inject the keystrokes:

```
tmux new-session -d -s pwd
tmux send-keys pwd C-m
tmux a -t pwd
```

Comment: Simply: `tmux new-session -d -s "pwd" 'bash -c "pwd;read"'`

Answer (score 0):

If you end your statement with `&& bash` then it will drop you into a shell when completed succesful. If you want to do that only when command fails then instead use `|| bash`.

E.g.

```
# Drops you into a shell if it fails, otherwise closes the window
tmux new-session -d -s "visited" 'bash -ic "visited --server" || bash'; 

# Drops you into a shell when finished successful, otherwise closes window.
tmux new-session -d -s "visited" 'bash -ic "visited --server" && bash'; 

# Always drops you into a shell when done. 
tmux new-session -d -s "visited" 'bash -ic "visited --server" || bash && bash';
```

Comment: I found that depending on how the process terminated, sometimes bash wouldn't run, even if I used a semi colon, e.g. `'bash -ic "visited --server"; bash'`. `send-keys` was better for me.